# iPhone video control and dual video playback

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller, playback

I need a way of controlling video non-fullscreen in my application. I've played around with both MPMoviePlayerController and a solution using UIWebViews.

I have found one solution using MPMoviePlayerController where I can prevent the video from going full screen (by grabbing the key window and set a transform on the UIWindow object). However, the MPMoviePlayerController doesn't seem to provide a method for pausing and resuming the playback. If I use the stop method, the video will hide (as specified in the api). Also, I need to be able to set the playback position during playback (manual seeking etc). I have seen apps that does this in the app store, but I'm not sure if they were deployed before Apple banned private method calls.

Does anyone have any tips or tricks related to this? (keep in mind that my app need to be accepted for the app store)

I'm not interested in FFMpeg solutions, due to licensing restrictions.

I'd also like to have playback of two videos at the same time, and would like some tips on this as well (however, I consider it not possible at the moment as MPMoviePlayerController will only play one video at the time).

Comment: Hi, have u got the solution how to fully control the video such as seek with pre-defined time，repeat in a duration etc.

Comment: But take a look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback. Check the currentPlaybackTime property description: "Changing the value of this property moves the playhead to the new location."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 3.2 and greater you can create in-line video players. Just add the MPMoviePlayerController's view property as a subview to your content view, set the frame and the URL source (local/remote) and voila. You have a non-fullscreen video player. Check out the documentation for MPMoviePlayerController for more details. (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html)